# Is $f(N)$ countable?

Tags: combinatorics, functions, elementary-set-theory

EDIT: The original question is: Let $N$ be a countable set and $f$ a function that maps $N$ onto a set $M$. Prove that $M$ is countable.

Consider a countable set $N$ which the function $f$ maps [on]to a set $M$. I want to prove that the set $M$ also is countable, if $N$ is. The thing I am unsure about, is if $f(N)=M$?

Here is my proof, though:

*Proof*. Let $N \subset X$ be a countable set and $f:X \rightarrow Y$.

Therefore, $N\cup f(N)=\left \{ x_1, f(x_1), x_2, f(x_2),...,x_n,f(x_n) \right \}$ which can be expressed as

$N\cup f(N)=\left \{x_1,f(x_1)  \right \}\cup\left \{x_2,f(x_2) \right \}\cdots \cup\left \{x_n,f(x_n)  \right \}$.

Theorem (*), picked from *Set Theory and Matrices* by I. Kaplansky : **A countable union of countable sets is countable**.

Since we have a union of $n$ sets in which there is two elements, $N\cup f(N)$ is therefore countable according to (*).

Since $N$ is defined as countable and $N\cup f(N)$ is countable, thus $f(N)$ is countable.

The question is though, is $f(N)$ referred as "the same thing" as $M$? If the purpose is proving that an arbitrary set $M$ is countable, I am totally lost.

Does anyone here have any suggestions?

Comment: Take $N = \{1\}$ and $M = \mathbb{R}$, then define the map $f : N \to M$ by $f(1) = 47$.  $N$ is countable, but $M$ is not.  In other words, the *range* of a function needn't be the entire *codomain*.  If the result is to be true, then $f$ needs to be surjective, I suppose (meaning that $f(N) = M$).

Comment: How does one prove that $M$ is countable though?

Comment: Well, obviously $f(N) = \{f(n)|n \in \mathbb N$ is countable as $f$ is a surjective function onto $f(N)$.  However if $f$ in not surjective to $M$ and $f(N) \subsetneq M$ that's not a damn thing you can say about the countability of $M$.  For examaple.  Let $i: \mathbb N \to \mathbb R$ via $i(n) = n$.  Then we have a surjection (actually a bijection) from $\mathbb N \to i(\mathbb N) = \mathbb N\subsetneq \mathbb R$.  So $i(\mathbb N) = \mathbb N$ is countable.  But what can we say about $\mathbb R$ being countable?  Not a damned thing.

Comment: "How does one prove that M is countable though?"  You don't have a hope in hell of being able to do that.  $M$ can be *any* set that has $f(N)$ as a proper subset and that can have *any* cardinality at least as high as $\mathbb N$.  and Xander just *gave* you an example where $M$ is *NOT* countable.

Comment: "The original question is: Let N be a countable set and f a function that maps N ***!!!onto!!!*** a set M".  If $f$ is ***!!!onto!!!*** then $f(N) = M$.  That is what *onto* means.

Comment: In other news, prepositions matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An essential missing condition in your stated problem is that $M$ is defined by the set of points reachable as $f(n)$ for some $n\in N$.  That is, $f:N\rightarrow M$ is surjective. You could say that the statement "$N$ maps to $M$ implies that condition, but it is nice to be clear about it.

With that understood, the outline of the proof that was probably wanted is that since $N$ is countable, there is some surjective counting function $k: \Bbb{N} \rightarrow N$.  Now consider the map $g : \Bbb{N} \rightarrow M$ such that for all $i \in \Bbb{N}$,
$$
g(i) = k(f(i))
$$
Because $k$ is surjective, the map $g$ applies $f(n)$ to every member of $N$, and then because $f$ is surjective onto $M$, that covers every member of $M$.

This proof is not rigorous but can be made rigorous without introducing any new ideas or theorems.

The proof you presented has the weakness that it uses a stronger theorem than is really necessary (countable union of countable sets), but it isn't actually wrong.

Answer (score 0):

$N$ is countable.

That means there is an $A\subset \mathbb N$ and an $j$ so that $j:A \to N$ is bijective.

We are told $f: N\to M$ is !ONTO!.  Because $f$ is *ONTO* that *means* $f(N) = M$.  We were *given* that.

So $h=f\circ j: A\subset \mathbb N \to N \to M$ is onto.  We can use $h:A \to M$ directly and not have to deal with the intermediate set $N$ anymore.  That'll make things easier.

But we don't know that $h$ is injective; just that it is onto.

But let $B \subset A \subset \mathbb N$ be defined like this:  for each $m \in M$ there are one or more $n_i \in A$ so that $f(n_i)=m$.  Let the *least* of those $n_i$ be in $B$ but none of the others.

Let $h': B \to M$ via $h'(n) = h(n)$ for each $n \in B$.

$h'$ is a bijection.

Pf: $h'$ is onto:  For every $m \in M$ there are $n_i\in A$ so that $h(n_i) = m$ and if $n$ is the least of the $n_i$ then $n\in B$ and $h'(n) =m$.

$h'$ is one to one:  If $h'(n) = h'(k) = m$ then $n,k \in A$ and $h(n) = h(k) = m$.  But if $n\ne k$ then only the smaller of them were in $B$.  So $n$ and $k$ can't be different as they are in $B$.  So $n=k$.

So $h'$ is a bijection from $B\subset \mathbb N$ to $M$ so $M$ is countable.

[Intuitively if $f: A \to B$ is *onto* then the cardinality of $B$ is "at most" the cardinality of $A$ because every thing in $B$ is mapped from an element in $A$.]